# Booting ubuntu and windows acer aspire s7

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, multi-boot, bootloader, acer-aspire

i have an acer aspire s7, and have been trying to dual boot ubuntu and windows on the same system unsuccessfully:
1 I am having problems getting the aspire s7 to recognise my bbot usb drive then also when it  does strangely sometimes the partitioning is a problem.

2. Where should the installed Ubuntu boot loader go.
3. When installed how do i boot to windows as well.

can anyone please give me the right way to do it.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Try running [Boot Repair](http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/).

Comment: Assuming its not installed as of yet (mentioned  where to put grub )

Answer (score 0):

Assuming its not installed as of yet (mentioned  where to put grub )

1) AT BOOT TIME look for the one time boot `Boot Order /  Setup` Option, select the USB  --side note: Depending on Windows version and config /motherboard model EFI may or may not work native.

2) it goes on the drive itself  (again assuming only one Booting drive  post install ) this would be /dev/sda

3) If grub sees windows  when installer is running grub-install you should see (after install but before reboot -- OR via tty )  /boot/Windows Loader  Or some such entry to indicate the windows install

IF NOT  Reboot to the USB  and chroot into the install ( can use lines 79-90 of my github writeup for that https://gist.github.com/linux-modder/55e49074ff947ca0f97c) for help chroot'ing in to the install.

Once chrooted in   run:

> sudo update-grub

this should now show a

> "Found  Windows $ver  on /dev/sdXY